# WP: Passing variables through do_shortcode()?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using a combination Gravity Forms and ACF to extract some data used in a function:

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_2', 'email_form_after_submission', 10, 2 );
function email_form_after_submission( $entry, $form ) {

    $company = $entry[2];
    $name = $entry[20];
    $upload_url = GFFormsModel::get_upload_url( 2 );

    // Send email to contact person
    $to_contact = $entry[8];
    $subject_contact = get_field('email-survey-contact-person_title', 'option');
    $body_contact = do_shortcode(get_field('email-survey-contact-person_content', 'option'));

    …

    wp_mail( $to_contact, $subject_contact, $body_contact, $headers );

}
```

I've also set up a few shortcodes that I want to take action with the `do_shortcode()` function.

The thing is, I'm trying to pass variables from within the function pasted above, but I can't seem to do this.

```
function shortcode_document() {

    return $entry[21];

}
add_shortcode( 'document', 'shortcode_document' );
```

The `get_field()` from the first code snippet is just a big textarea, where you can use these predefined shortcodes, such as `[document]`.

I know it doesn't make sense not using a global variable (I tried putting `global $entry` outside the first function), but I'm sure this has worked before. I now have WordPress 4.9.8.

Thanks in advance for any guidance

Comment: Is your ACF-field saved like [field]? If not you need to add [] surrounding the field name.